# HC-SR04 systematically finding a weird value

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, hc-sr04

I have a HC-SR04 connected to my Arduino. its all working very nice. Yet with a constant interval a weird value appears (see the Serial Plot picture). I am wondering what causes this. I will soon upload my Sketch (Making it bit more readable).

Or are there to many possible factors that could influence the HC-SR04 behaviour that it is impossible to determine the cause?

[image: Y-axis shows distance in cm, x-axis iteration (once a second)]

Y-axis shows distance in cm, x-axis shows iteration (once a second)

Thanks in advance!

Kind Regards, a fellower Arduino User

Comment: It's probably less likely the HC-SR04 and more likely Arduino interrupts and `micros()` jitter.

Comment: Yes I am using millis() ! To make my distance sensor not lockup the remaining of the sketch

Comment: I am thinking more with the `pulseIn()` function that is commonly used for reading the HC-SR04. That uses `micros()` for the timing, and if that gets interrupted (by the timer0 millis() interrupt, or a serial interrupt, for instance) it could skew the results.

Comment: Sounds logic, aswell as I do use PulseIn and serial connection. Is there a way I can Predict when it occurs?

Comment: For absolute precision, you should be using one of the timer Input Compare peripherals, though I don't know of an Arduino library offhand that does it.